# Perl Net::Dbus ByteArray

Tags: perl

Использую Perl с модулем Net::Dbus.

Необходимо сделать параметр **ssid** типа dbus ByteArray.

В рабочем примере на python это выглядит так:

```
s_wifi = dbus.Dictionary({'ssid': dbus.ByteArray("homewifi"),
    'security': '802-11-wireless-security'})
```

Kак это сделать  на Perl?

```
my %s_wifi = ( 'ssid' => ???('homewifi'), 'security' => '802-11-wireless-security' );
```

PS:
Пробовал так

```
my $ssid = 'homewifi';
my @ssid = split('' , $ssid);
my $tssid = dbus_array(\@ssid);
my %s_wifi = ( 'ssid' => $tssid, 'security' => '802-11-wireless-security' );
```

ничего не меняется - пишет как и прежде
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.MissingProperty: ssid

полный код положил [сюда](https://pastebin.com/S8i8PB3b)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, о чём именно речь. Но [dbus_array](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::DBus#DATA-TYPING-METHODS) - не оно?

Comment: обновил сообщение

Comment: Не нужно передавать ссылку на массив в dbus_array, ссылка на массив - это в лучшем случае 64-х битное число (смещение), либо вовсе что-то в духе "ARRAY(0xdf6cb8)". Передайте саму строку: dbus_array($ssid). Мне не на чем проверить, но есть сильное подозрение, что я прав.